# What's the relation of runtime and runtime targets in MyApp.deps.json file and libraries copied to the bin\Release folder?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to understand the change that happened between .NET Framework 4.5-ish and the new .NET Runtime 8.0 in the treatment of libraries, and the files that are output to the `bin\Release` folder.

Items in question are the new format `MyApp.csproj` file and `MyApp.deps.json` file.
Due to some older WPF code apart form depending on frameworks `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` I also have package `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility`.

In that last package `System.Data.SqlClient` reference is present. So when I build the app two copies of the file are being created:

(1) `bin\Release\net8.0-windows\System.Data.SqlClient.dll`

(2) `bin\Release\net8.0-windows\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp2.1\System.Data.SqlClient.dll`

Hopefully relevant part of MyApp.deps.json is below:

```json
      "System.Data.SqlClient/4.8.5": {
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.Win32.Registry": "4.7.0",
          "System.Security.Principal.Windows": "5.0.0",
          "runtime.native.System.Data.SqlClient.sni": "4.7.0"
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Data.SqlClient.dll": {
            "assemblyVersion": "4.6.1.5",
            "fileVersion": "4.700.22.51706"
          }
        },
        "runtimeTargets": {
          "runtimes/unix/lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Data.SqlClient.dll": {
            "rid": "unix",
            "assetType": "runtime",
            "assemblyVersion": "4.6.1.5",
            "fileVersion": "4.700.22.51706"
          },
          "runtimes/win/lib/netcoreapp2.1/System.Data.SqlClient.dll": {
            "rid": "win",
            "assetType": "runtime",
            "assemblyVersion": "4.6.1.5",
            "fileVersion": "4.700.22.51706"
          }
        }
      },
```

I wasn't aware of the new runtime folder so when my post-build xcopy script kicked off `runtimes` folder didn't get copied and I had to troubleshoot what the issue was.
I narrowed it down to the copy of the `System.Data.SqlClient.dll` in runtimes folder (there were also other libraries but this one came up as the first error when I tried running my app).

Out of curiosity I later deleted the copy of the DLL in the root folder (bin\Release) but that one seems irrelevant to the correct functioning of the app. So the first few questions are:

#1 - What are the two copies of `System.Data.SqlClient.dll`? They have the same version and product version but are of different size and as stated they are located in different place. Isn't this file part of the .NET Runtime 8.0 installer?

#2 - What is the copy of the DLL in the root folder for, if it is not used and can be safely deleted and the app does not ever attempt to load it? Why does the build process create this file in the first place?

#3 - What is the general purpose of the `runtimes` folder and why are some DLLs located in `win\lib` subfolder while others in `win-x64\native` ?

The following code ties into the next couple of questions related to the MyApp.csproj file:

```
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

#4 - With this configuration: why is there a `freebsd` or `osx` folder created in the `runtimes` folder even though I clearly don't intend to build the app for FreeBSD? Is there a way I can control what is being copied to the `runtimes` folder?

#5 - What would be a simple way to understand the difference between the 3 configuration settings above? (I checked the documentation, but I wasn't able to translate that information into tangible difference between these 3 settings. And all of them have to be there from what I can tell after my journey of porting my app from .NET Framework to .NET Runtime.)

Many thanks to everyone who could help with any of these questions.

Comment: A good place to start is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview?source=recommendations